# Selecting specific slides for handout?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<+->
      \item<2,3,5,7,11>  
      \item<2,4,6,8,10,12>
      \item<3,6,9,12>
      \item<5,10>
      \item<1-6>
      \item<+->
      \item<7-12>
      \item<1-3>
      \item<4-6>
      \item<7-9>
      \item<9-12>
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In this frame, I use, as I am sometimes forced to do, hard coded slide numbers. The question is however valid, and perhaps even with greater might, to the case where one uses relative offsets and manual tweaking of the `beamerpauses` counter.

I would like to select specific slides to be included in the handouts. Something of the sort of `\begin{frame}<handout:5,11>`, but this does something else as far as I could determine.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: You can add the `handout` option, as in `\item<nums| handout:1>` to print the corresponding items on handouts, or `\item<nums| handout:0>` to delete items you don't want to include in the handouts

Comment: I may have missed something but as far as I can tell, you can only formulate one slide per frame for the handout since everything gets flattened. So if you would like to include 3 frames worth, the only thing I've figured out to do is to add another 2 frames with the extra material and typeset it using \mode<handout> to exclude it from the presentation. `beamer` does presentations beautifully, for the most part, but my colleagues are astonished at what it cannot do with regard to handouts. I've assumed good support must just be rather difficult to achieve in LaTeX but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I just answered a similar question, maybe it might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356907/88735

Answer (score 5):

You can select invidual slides in a handout as you want; you just need to specify that the relevant overlay commands apply in `handout` mode too (specifications with no mode default to `beamer:`).  If you only want to use `beamer` and `handout` modes then it's easiest to do this with the mode key `all:`

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:5,7>
  \scriptsize
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<all:+->
      \item<all:2,3,5,7,11>  
      \item<all:2,4,6,8,10,12>
      \item<all:3,6,9,12>
      \item<all:5,10>
      \item<all:1-6>
      \item<all:+->
      \item<all:7-12>
      \item<all:1-3>
      \item<all:4-6>
      \item<all:7-9>
      \item<all:9-12>
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.