# How to include, in beamer handout, a slide exactly as it appears in presentation mode on a particular transition?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a beamer presentation where I do something like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\include{tikz}% To get \foreach

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  These I want to uncover one by one in presentation mode, but to appear
  as a single slide in the handout

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\def\slideContent{
  These I want to uncover one by one in presentation mode *and* do the same
  in the handout. But that's not what I get!

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
  \end{itemize}
}

\foreach \i in {1, ..., 4} {
  \begin{frame}<\i>
    \slideContent
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

The first frame is generated as expected in handout mode, but the last 4 frames are not since handout collapses *all* effects onto a single slide. And that's not what I want. Instead, I want those last 4 slides to appear exactly as they do in presentation mode. I know this can somehow be achieved by explicitly adding `handout:0` to suppress effects from the handout, but I have some really complicated figures where it's just not maintainable to go in and do this for each and every single overlay. Note that this is not about *excluding certain slides*, because then I would have just added `handout:0` to those slides, but here it's more about limiting the effects seen at handout to a certain number of transitions.

So, in a nutshell, how can I get handout mode to behave exactly as the presentation mode for certain slides?

Comment: You can use separate overlay specifications for presentation and handout mode with, e.g., `\only<n|handout:m>{<content>}`. I'll try to elaborate later when I have some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally got what I was looking for, but I had to completely circumvent usage of `handout` mode.

What I did was to use `pdftk` to take the `beamer` mode PDF, and chop it up in order to produce the `handout` mode PDF, like so:

```
pdftk presentation.pdf cat 1 6 10-20 60-70 76 81 [...] output handout.pdf
```

It's not the best solution since you have to manually pick which slides to keep, but since the command is embedded into a Makefile, and it's rare for me to add or remove slides, it's good enough to automate the task of producing the handout whenever I fix some bug in the slides.

Answer (score 8):

A workaround on your problem is to temporarily change from handout to beamer mode while compiling. This way you can select a subset of slides, exactly as they are compiled in presentation mode. The trick is to change the internal variable `\beamer@currentmode` that Beamer uses (I don't know if messing with this can break any thing). I created a new environment to encapsulate this change for my slides, so I hope it can be useful.

What you have to do is:

1. copy the definitions to the preamble
2. put your frame in a `\begin{handoutframeselect}[2,4-5]`, changing the specification to whatever you need
3. put a selection macro in front of your frame: `\begin{frame}<\slideselection>`

The macro `\slideselection` will select the whole set of slides when in presentation mode, but only you specification when in handout mode. Check the example:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifOnBeamerModeTransition
\newcommand{\slideselection}{1-}%
\newenvironment{handoutframeselect}[1][1-]{%
  \begingroup%
  \mode<handout>{%
    \gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}%
    \OnBeamerModeTransitiontrue%
    \renewcommand{\slideselection}{#1}}%
}{%
  \ifOnBeamerModeTransition%
    \OnBeamerModeTransitionfalse%
    \gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}%
  \fi%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Normal frame}
No selection in this frame:
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item slide 1
  \item slide 2
  \item slide 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{handoutframeselect}[2,4-5]
\begin{frame}<\slideselection>{Custom frame}
slideselection will be
\begin{itemize}
\item 1- in beamer mode
\item 2,4-5 in handout mode
\end{itemize}

This slides will be shown : \slideselection
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item custom slide 1
  \item custom slide 2
  \item custom slide 3
  \item custom slide 4
  \item custom slide 5
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{handoutframeselect}

\begin{frame}{Other normal frame}
In this frame, we return to handout mode, no selection either:
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item slide 1
  \item slide 2
  \item slide 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Great answer, thank you a lot! Please note that there is an improvement of it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455444/beamer-overlays-and-handout-exclude-frames-from-handout/455459#455459) that still allows to show only a subset of the frames in presentation mode. As you write, your solution shows *all* slides in the presentation mode. Specifying "standard" subsets is also not possible anymore, since your code requires to give "\slideselection" instead. To solve this issue, I have parametrized this command to allow specifying the subsets again.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply overlay specifications separately to `beamer` and `handout` mode by adding `|handout:"overlay specification"` after the initial (beamer) specification. In your first list you have `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`, which flattens everything onto one handout frame because no overlay specifications are given to say otherwise. If you change this to `\begin{itemize}[<+-|handout:+->]`, the `+-` behavior will apply to handout mode as well. I hope this usage is clear in the code below.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  These I want to uncover one by one in presentation mode, but to appear
  as a single slide in the handout
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  These I want to uncover one by one in presentation mode *and* do the same
  in the handout. But that's not what I get!
  \begin{itemize}[<+-|handout:+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then I have to write this at _each and every overlay_ specification. And as I said, there are like a hundred of them, so I really don't want to have to do that. Is there no way of just saying "Hey! On _this_ slide you should generated the handout _exactly_ as you did in `beamer` mode"?

Comment: Try using `\begin{itemize}[<handout:+->]` in your definition of `slideContent`.

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm trying to say is that I have a hundred "`\begin{itemize}<[+-]>`" on which I would have to do this change - these slides contains complicated TikZ figures, where I heavily make use of `<...>` in order to make nodes appear and disappear - and therefore I'm wonder if there is _some other way_ of achieving the same effect, but with much fewer augmentations.

Comment: Since you had explicitly defined `slideContent` I assumed you were using it in multiple places, in which case changing the definition would affect the entire document. 

In what way would you like `handout` mode to behave different to `beamer` mode? If you basically want the behavior to be the same I see no reason for using `handout` mode.

Comment: I used `\slideContent` in order to get a new slide number for each transition, but in this case I could have done without that macro and defined the content directly within the frame. However, my problem remains. The thing is that I don't want to change the behavior of `handout` to be exactly like `beamer` mode _for the entire document_. I only want this behavior to be enforced _for certain slides_; in this case, the second frame and not the first frame.